# How to attach a given Taxonomy to the TaxonomyField of a custom ContentPart in OrchardCMS

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

Seen [this post](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/5601#issuecomment-127271767) and I have a **Taxonomy** named "Area" that is perfectly visible from my Dashboard.
I also have a ContentType  with a **ContentPart** that has a field of type Taxonomy with the same name "Area" :

            `ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("GolfCoursePart", p => p
                //Area Taxonomy
                  .WithField("AreaTaxonomy", fcfg => fcfg
                  .OfType("TaxonomyField")
                  .WithDisplayName("Area")
                  .WithSetting("Hint", "Area this Golf Course belongs to")
                  .WithSetting("Taxonomy", "Area")
                  .WithSetting("LeavesOnly", "true")
                  .WithSetting("SingleChoice", "false")
                  .WithSetting("Required", "true"))`

But there's still missing the link between the ContentPart and the Taxonomy and I have to do it through the UI. **How can I do it programmatically? (not using the Dashboard??)**
[image: alt]

I don't want to use recipes to define Content Types, I could use them to define Taxonomies but not  my custom ContentTypes and ContentPats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the settings' prefixes: 'TaxonomyFieldSettings'. Try the following:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("GolfCoursePart", p => p
    //Area Taxonomy
    .WithField("AreaTaxonomy", fcfg => fcfg
    .OfType("TaxonomyField")
    .WithDisplayName("Area")

    // TaxonomyFieldSettings
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Hint", "Area this Golf Course belongs to")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Taxonomy", "Area")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.LeavesOnly", "true")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.SingleChoice", "false")
    .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Required", "true"))
```